# different instantiation of members in singleton class

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

as title says, is there any difference between this:

```
    public final class Foo {

        private static final Foo foo;

        private final ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
        //other members
        public static Foo getFooInstance(){
              if(foo == null)
              { 
                  foo = new Foo();
               }
              return foo;   
    }
       public ArrayList<String> getList(){
              return text;   
    }
```

and

```
 public final class Foo {

        private static final Foo foo = new Foo();
        private final ArrayList<String> text;
        private Foo(){
        //other members
         text = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        public static Foo getFooInstance(){
              return foo;   
    }
     public ArrayList<String> getList(){
              return text;   
    }
```

i think there is no difference,to be more clear, i posted this question.

Comment: yes. in your first example, Foo is not a singleton.
you can call Foo f = new Foo(); a thousand times, and i 'll create a new instance each time

Comment: If you added a `private Foo() {}` to your first example they would be equivalent.

Comment: i forgot this, see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to initialize the final instance members?

Both are valid way for `final` variable to initialize it either in constructor or at the time of declaration itself.

You can use one more way to initialize the final instance variable inside the `initialization` block.

Sample code:

```
public final class Foo {

    private final ArrayList<String> text;

    // initialization block
    {
       text = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

### Singleton Design Pattern

[Singleton](http://idiotechie.com/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/) is a part of [Gang of Four](http://idiotechie.com/gang-of-four-gof-design-pattern/) design pattern and it is categorized under creational design patterns.

- Your first solution is using  **lazily initialized** singleton pattern. Use **Double check locking** singleton pattern to make it thread safe.
- Your second solution is more secure in case of MultiThreading where the instance is initialized at the time of declaration itself.

Read more about here [Singleton Design Pattern – An Introspection w/ Best Practices](http://java.dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern-%E2%80%93)

Comment: i know that, see my edit, my question is not focused on final but on singleton.